# On Page Load select option jquery like user behaviour (Real Time Change Event Fire)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to autoselect select box option on page load. Here is my code which is not working.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".configure_supre_select_1 option:eq(1)")
    .attr('selected',true)
    .trigger('change');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For make real time click by jquery i added below code. It used "Event".

For change select option on page load i use below code:

```
jQuery(".configure_supre_select_1").val(jQuery(".configure_supre_select_1 option:eq(1)").val()).change();
```

and then make it real time changing i use below code:

```
var dropdown = $("SelectAttributeId"); // Id of select box
var element = dropdown;
var event = 'change';
var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent(event, true, true );
return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are triggering the selected option instead of the select - also use prop

```
$(function(){
  $(".configure_supre_select_1 option:eq(1)").prop('selected',true);
  $(".configure_supre_select_1").trigger('change');
});
```

Alternatively set the value

```
$(function(){
  $(".configure_supre_select_1").val("firstOptionValue").change();         
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".configure_supre_select_1").on("change", function() {
    $(".optdiv").hide();
    var val = this.value;
    if (val) {
      $("#" + val.replace("OptionValue", "")).show();
    }
  });
  $(".configure_supre_select_1").val("firstOptionValue").change();
  
  $(".configure_supre_select_2 option:eq(1)").prop('selected',true);
  $(".configure_supre_select_2").trigger('change');
  
});
```

```css
.optdiv {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="configure_supre_select_1">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="firstOptionValue">First</option>
  <option value="secondOptionValue">Second</option>
</select>
<div class="optdiv" id="first">First is selected</div>
<div class="optdiv" id="second">Second is selected</div>
<hr />

Here I use your version <br/>

<select class="configure_supre_select_2">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="firstOptionValue">First</option>
  <option value="secondOptionValue">Second</option>
</select>
```

Comment: "It's not working"  is not very helpful. Any console errors? Did you load jQuery? Did you make a typo? Did I make a typo?

Comment: @ChiragRajput “Not working” is not a valid problem description.

Comment: There is not any console error when page load. Also i am using "jquery-1.11.3.min.js"

Comment: jQuery(".configure_supre_select_1 option:eq(1)").prop('selected',true);
   jQuery(".configure_supre_select_1").trigger('change');


This is not working on page load. its working when i try it run through console.

Comment: Please see example